# SQL to return all related rows in a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I've seen references to recursion in SQL Server, but I'm using MySQL and require the result to be in a single column. If I have a table of relationships:

```
itemID1 | itemiD2
---------------
  1     |   2
  1     |   3
  4     |   5
```

How do I select all IDs related to a single ID in either column? For example:

1 ==> 2,3

3 ==> 1,2

I tried self joins, but can't get all related IDs in a single column. If there's a better schema for this it's not too late to change the table.

Thank you.

Comment: In what sense is `3` related to `2`? It doesn't appear to be based on the example you've shown.

Comment: seems the relation is transitive here ;] if 1 is related to 2, and 1 is related to 3 then 2 is related to 3. :] just kidding. Ian Levy, we need to know this.

Comment: Looks like a `friends of friends` kind of problem.

Comment: seems easy if you know how "deep" to follow the relation. unsolvable if infinitely.

Comment: Apologies if wasn't clear: this is indeed a friend of friend problem (beautiful terminology). Context: this is a 'related article' table, so if article A is related to articles B and C, each one should be related to the others. One level deep only.

Comment: Ian, could you please edit the question to include your last comment? Visitors usually do not take time to browse through comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this query:

```
select
    itemID1, group_concat(cast(itemID2 as char) separator ',')
from
(
    select itemID1, itemID2 from st where itemID1 = :ID
    union 
    select itemID2, itemID1 from st where itemID2 = :ID
    union
    select s1.itemID2, s2.itemID2 from st as s1 inner join st as s2 on s1.itemID1 = s2.itemID1
    where s1.itemID2 = :ID
    union
    select s1.itemID1, s2.itemID1 from st as s1 inner join st as s2 on s1.itemID2 = s2.itemID2
    where s1.itemID1 = :ID
) as subquery
where itemID1 <> itemID2
group by itemID1
```

This way you select relation in both ways (`union` provides distinctiveness) as well as relation between joined items (also in both ways).

Comment: this is also wrong. No -1 'cos of the difficulty of the question. The big question here is how do you specify the where clause to get the desired result

Comment: Kuba, otherwise its pretty easy :)

Comment: OK, now it includes :ID parameter. Verified with sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29cf4/6

Comment: Kuba, this works for just the first level. May be OP is ok with it. To be honest, the challenge of this puzzle lies in getting recursion done..

Comment: OMG... please notice my comment 50 mins ago under the question. ^_^ Ian wanted one level only. Arbitrary level depth is unsolvable without recursion and this MySQL do not provide.  (what "OP" stands for btw??)

Comment: Kuba, that is fine. I know too. I said it in my comment. I wasn't trashing, I was saying the real challenge lies in getting recursion done. OP means original poster :)

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer to the question.  this doesn't address the recursion but rather the transitivity.

```
select itemID1, itemID2
from ((select itemID1, itemID2
       from t
      ) union all
      (select itemID2, itemID1
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by itemID1, itemID2
```

To get them as a list:

```
select itemID1, group_concat(distinct cast(itemID2 as varchar(32)) separator ',')
from ((select itemID1, itemID2
       from t
      ) union all
      (select itemID2, itemID1
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by itemID1, itemID2
```

Comment: Gordon, there must be one level relation (consult comments under question) so you must extend your unions with some joins...

Comment: @KubaWyrostek . . . you are right . . . I misread the data.  I'll revise the answer to make it a partial answer.

Comment: [...] WHERE itemID1 = x OR itemID2 = x

Comment: @IanLevy my question is where do you specify that in the query? I do not think it yields the result.

Comment: @nawfal . . . you put a where clause in a query before a group by.  If you wanted to select for one id, you would say "where itemID1 = <whatever>".  However, as I clarified in the answer, this doesn't solve the problem.  I would have deleted the answer, but figured it might prove useful for someone else, since it solves (the easy) half.